# My question is about Code Explosion in generics c#

Tags: c#, .net

The CLR does not create a separate native code for reference types because all reference types are of same size(32 bits or 64 bits) and CLR creates a specific native code for value types because they differ in size.

Though int32 and uint32 are of same size, CLR generates a separate native code for each.

Why is this so?

Comment: "because all reference types are of same size(32 bits or 64 bits)" Eeeeeh, what? Surely not. However the **references** to instances of those types have the same size.

Comment: I'm very confused by the question. What do you mean by "generates a native code"?

Comment: @DavidG see here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/09/18/runtime-representation-of-genericspart-2/ . The question is about the first bold statement in that article "**compiled method bodies on closed generic types that have reference type parameters can be shared**": why doesn't the same sharing also apply to value types which the same size.

Comment: He probably means that the jitter will produce in-memory representations of the generic code once per value type involved, compared to reference types where it produces the code once, period.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it occurred to the people making this that many types both in the runtime and out in the wild will have the same size. I'm assuming there are some pitfalls here that aren't readily evident to us, that either prevented this outright, or made it much harder than they wanted to invest time in.

Comment: You may want to read [Joe Duffy's article on generics](http://joeduffyblog.com/2011/10/23/on-generics-and-some-of-the-associated-overheads/). About half way down: "It is true that, in theory, `List<DateTime>` and `List<Int64>` could use the same shared code, because they are of identical size and have GC roots in the same locations (trivially, because neither has one). But there are additional restrictions on generated code that makes this problematic..."

Comment: @HimBromBeere yeah sorry, that's what i meant