# During JIT Compilation,why for different value-types different codes will be generated but where as for reference types single code will be generated

Tags: c#

Using Generics, if the generic type is a value type, then at run time different copies will be created, but for reference types, only single copy (or a duplicate copy of the code) will be maintained rather than duplicate copy for each and every Reference type?

And the next question that follows is if there is a static constructor, will there be a change in maintaining the copies by the JIT compiler.

Comment: In terms of memory layout, reference types are all *the same* (a reference to the heap), but value-types are *all different* (different numbers of members, types, sizes etc).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55022244/my-question-is-about-code-explosion-in-generics-c-sharp . There are some good links in the comment to that question, but no answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good explanation in the Generics chapter, CLR via C#, by Jeffrey Richter.

> The CLR has another optimization: the CLR considers all reference type arguments to be identical, and so again, the code can be shared. For example, the code compiled by the CLR for `List<String>`'s methods can be used for `List<Stream>`'s methods, because `String` and `Stream` are both reference types. In fact, for any reference type, the same code will be used. The CLR can perform this optimization because all reference type arguments or variables are really just pointers (all 32 bits on a 32-bit Windows system and 64 bits on a 64-bit Windows system) to objects on the heap, and object pointers are all manipulated in the same way.
>
> But if any type argument is a value type, the CLR must produce native code specifically for that value type. The reason is because value types can vary in size. And even if two value types are the same size (such as `Int32` and `UInt32`, which are both 32 bits), the CLR still can’t share the code because different native CPU instructions can be used to manipulate these values.

You might want to read the whole book if you are interested in CLR internals.

Answering the second question about static constructor - there are no special changes. Static constructor will be called for each created closed generic type.